# Is it possible to stream data(Upload) to store on bucket of Google cloud storage and allow to download at the same time?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to stream data(Upload) to store on bucket of Google cloud storage and allow to download at the same time?
I have tried to use the Cloud API to upload a 100MB file to the bucket by using the code as below, but during the upload, and i refresh the bucket in the Google cloud console, i cannot see the new uploading file until the upload is finished. I would like to upload realtime video encoded in H.264 to store on the Cloud storage, so the size is unknown and at the same time, other users can start downloading the file event it is uploading. So is it possible?

```
  Test code:

  File tempFile = new File("StorageSample");
  RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(tempFile, "rw");
  try
  {
      raf.setLength(1000 * 1000 * 100);
  }
  finally
  {
      raf.close();
  }

  uploadFile(TEST_FILENAME, "text/plain", tempFile, bucketName);

public static void uploadFile(
  String name, String contentType, File file, String bucketName)
  throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException 
{
    InputStreamContent contentStream = new InputStreamContent(
    contentType, new FileInputStream(file));
    // Setting the length improves upload performance
    contentStream.setLength(file.length());
    StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject()
    // Set the destination object name
    .setName(name)
    // Set the access control list to publicly read-only
    .setAcl(Arrays.asList(
        new ObjectAccessControl().setEntity("allAuthenticatedUsers").setRole("READER"))); //allUsers//

    // Do the insert
    Storage client = StorageFactory.getService();
    Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest = client.objects().insert(
    bucketName, objectMetadata, contentStream);   
    insertRequest.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(false);  

    insertRequest.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible, as state in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms):

> Objects are immutable, which means that an uploaded object cannot
>   change throughout its storage lifetime. An object's storage lifetime
>   is the time between successful object creation (upload) and successful
>   object deletion.

This means that an object in cloud storage starts to exist when the upload it's finished, so you cannot access the object until your upload it's not completed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So do you have any suggestion on how i could do the  function i expected? Thanks

Comment: A possible solution, would be divide you big object in smaller chunks with a specific naming convention. In this way as soon an small object has been uploaded the user can start the streaming of the content. You will need to handle an intelligent buffering and the iteration over the different objects, to give a smooth experience to the user.